# Function with @SchedulerLock not running when manually triggered for the second time even after removing entry from shedLock table

Tags: java, spring-boot, cron, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

I have a function with following annotations:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${cron.expression}")
@SchedulerLock(name = "scheduleJobsWithQuartz", lockAtLeastFor = "15m", lockAtMostFor = "30m")
public void xyz() {
///
}
```

This function runs once a day but it can be manually triggered from a GET call as well.
When i start the pod and execute the GET call for the first time, the function runs, but when i hit the GET call again after sometime, it doesn't run even after I manually delete the entry from shedLock table.

Is the schedulerLock information stored somewhere else as well? If it is stored in the memory, can I access it somehow?

Here are my application properties:

```
QUARTZ_JOBSTORE_DRIVER_DELEGATECLASS : org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
QUARTZ_JOBSTORE_MISFIRETHRESHOLD : 60000
QUARTZ_JOBSTORE_TABLE_PREFIX : qrtz_
QUARTZ_SCHEDULER_INSTANCE_NAME : MyClusteredScheduler
QUARTZ_SCHEDULER_INSTANCE_ID : AUTO
QUARTZ_SCHEDULER_CLUSTER_INTERVAL : 20000
```

Comment: maybe you are missing something. `@SchedulerLock` is part of [schedlock](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock) so maybe you should delete something else than quartz db entry.